# C# WPF: Combination of Viewport3D and WriteableBitmap causes flickering in Viewport3D control

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, writeablebitmap, viewport3d

I have two WPF controls:

(1) a viewport3D control through the use of HelixViewport3D (from the Helix 3D Toolkit: http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/)

(2) an Image control that is written to with WriteableBitmap.WritePixels

I have a Kinect sensor that

- pushes skeleton data (via eventhandler SkeletonFrameReady) to the HelixViewPort3D control
- pushes the RGB camera data (via eventhandler ColorFrameReady) to the WriteableBitmap

**Problem**:

If I only update the viewport3D control, I get a working (non-flickering) 3D skeleton as per this page: http://kuchenzeit.wordpress.com/2012/10/12/tcd-kinect/

But if I am updating both the viewport3D control and the Image control, then I get flickering in my viewport3D control

Is there a way I can remove the flickering in the viewport3D control?